# $T$ Matrix elements in Scattering Theory (Sakurai 2nd edition)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, s-matrix-theory, matrix-elements

I am currently unable to see how the $T$ Matrix elements discussed in 6.1 of Sakurai's Modern Quantum mechanics 2$^\mathtt{nd}$ edition can be expressed as they are in equation (6.1.26) (see below). 
My specific question is why, after combining equations \eqref{6.1.23} and \eqref{6.1.24}, the second of the 3 terms "looks just like \eqref{6.1.23}, but with $T_\mathtt{ni}$ replaced with $V_\mathtt{ni}$ "? 
I instead get that the first and second term combined look exactly like the right-hand-side of \eqref{6.1.10}, except $t_0$ is replaced with $-\infty$ (to clarify: the main discrepancy between the expression I see and the expression the text suggests is that $T_\mathtt{ni}$ is not replaced with $V_\mathtt{ni}$ ).

If my question is too specific, I offer an alternative question: When I attempt to combine \eqref{6.1.23} and \eqref{6.1.24} and end up with \eqref{eqv}, what might clue me in that \eqref{eqv} must not be physical? For this question, my two best guesses are:

- The time-dependent perturbation theory developed in the previous chapter never required skipping index $m=n$
- The structure of \eqref{eqv} is not at all like matrix elements for any other textbook QM quantity

$T$ Matrix is defined in equation \eqref{6.1.10}, presumably so that integral converges when $ \ t_0=-\infty \ $ due to the $\varepsilon t$ term in the exponent.

$$
\left< \mathtt{n} \left| U_I\left( t,t_0 \right) \right| \mathtt{i} \right> =
\delta_\mathtt{ni} - \frac{i}{\hbar}T_\mathtt{ni}\int_{t_0}^t e^{i\omega_\mathtt{ni}t'+\varepsilon t'}dt' \tag{6.1.10}\label{6.1.10}
$$

Note that the right-hand-side term in \eqref{6.1.10} is equal to the right-hand-side term of \eqref{6.1.9} ( note: in the book, (6.1.9) has $\left< \mathtt{n} \left| V \right| \mathtt{i} \right>$ instead of $V_\mathtt{ni}$, but they are the same by definition )

$$
\left< \mathtt{n} \left| U_I\left( t,t_0 \right) \right| \mathtt{i} \right> =
\delta_\mathtt{ni} - \frac{i}{\hbar}V_\mathtt{ni}\int_{t_0}^t e^{i\omega_\mathtt{ni}t'}dt'
\tag{6.1.9}\label{6.1.9}
$$

Let's keep this in mind when combining (6.1.23) and (6.1.24)

$$
\left< \mathtt{n} \left| U_I\left(t,-\infty\right) \right| \mathtt{i} \right> = \delta_\mathtt{ni} + \frac{1}{\hbar}T_{\mathtt{ni}}\frac{e^{i\omega_\mathtt{ni}t+\varepsilon t}}{-\omega_\mathtt{ni}+i\varepsilon}
\tag{6.1.23}\label{6.1.23}
$$
$$
\left< \mathtt{n} \left| U_I\left(t,-\infty\right) \right| \mathtt{i} \right> =
\delta_{\mathtt{ni}} -
\frac{1}{\hbar}\sum_m V_\mathtt{nm}\int_{-\infty}^t e^{i\omega_\mathtt{nm}t'}
\left< \mathtt{m} \left| U_I\left(t',-\infty\right) \right| \mathtt{i} \right>dt'
\tag{6.1.24}\label{6.1.24}
$$
$$
\left< \mathtt{n} \left| U_I\left(t,-\infty\right) \right| \mathtt{i} \right> =
\delta_\mathtt{ni} - \frac{i}{\hbar}\sum_m V_\mathtt{nm}\int_{-\infty}^t dt' \ e^{i\omega_\mathtt{nm}t'} \left( \delta_\mathtt{mi} + \frac{1}{\hbar}T_\mathtt{mi}\frac{e^{i\omega_\mathtt{mi}t'+\varepsilon t'}}{-\omega_\mathtt{mi}+i\varepsilon} \right)
\tag{I}
$$
I am thinking that the term with the factor of $\delta_\mathtt{mi}$  is [after summation] the second term discussed in the paragraph between \eqref{6.1.24} and (6.1.25), which supposedly "looks just like \eqref{6.1.23}, but with $T_{\mathtt{ni}}$ replaced with $V_{\mathtt{ni}}$ ". However, since there is no term of $\varepsilon t$ in the exponent, I am quite sure the $\delta_\mathtt{mi}$ term, combined witht he first term $\delta_\mathtt{ni}$ gives:
$$
\delta_\mathtt{ni}-\frac{i}{\hbar}\sum_m V_\mathtt{nm}\int_{-\infty}^t dt' \ e^{i\omega_\mathtt{nm}t'} \delta_\mathtt{mi}=\delta_\mathtt{ni}-\frac{i}{\hbar}V_\mathtt{ni}\int_{-\infty}^t e^{i\omega_\mathtt{ni}t'}dt'
\tag{II}
$$
This is equivalent to \eqref{6.1.9} when $t_0=-\infty$ which is equivalent to \eqref{6.1.10} when $t_0=-\infty$ which is identical to \eqref{6.1.23} after doing the integration and multiplying by $\frac{i}{i}$. 
So, since (6.1.9,10,23) are all expressions for $\left< \mathtt{n} \left| U_I\left(t,-\infty\right) \right| \mathtt{i} \right>$, I get
$$
0=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{1}{\hbar}\sum_m \frac{V_\mathtt{nm}T_\mathtt{mi}}{-\omega_\mathtt{mi}+i\varepsilon}\int_{-\infty}^t e^{i\color{blue}{\left(\omega_\mathtt{nm}+\omega_\mathtt{mi}\right)}t'+\varepsilon t'} =
-\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{1}{\hbar}\sum_m \frac{V_\mathtt{nm}T_\mathtt{mi} e^{i\color{blue}{\omega_\mathtt{ni}} t + \varepsilon t } }{\left(-\omega_\mathtt{mi}+i\varepsilon\right)\left( i\color{blue}{\omega_\mathtt{ni}} + \varepsilon \right)}
\tag{III}
$$
instead of
$$
\color{red}{ \delta_\mathtt{ni} } + \color{grey}{ \frac{1}{\hbar} } T_\mathtt{ni}\frac{ \color{magenta}{ e^{\omega_\mathtt{ni}t + \varepsilon t } } }{ \color{green}{ \left( -\omega_\mathtt{ni} + i\varepsilon \right)} } =
\color{red}{ \delta_\mathtt{ni} } + \color{grey}{ \frac{1}{\hbar} } V_\mathtt{ni}\frac{ \color{magenta} { e^{\omega_\mathtt{ni}t + \varepsilon t } } }{ \color{green}{ \left( -\omega_\mathtt{ni} + i\varepsilon \right) } }
+ \frac{1}{\hbar} \color{grey}{ \frac{1}{\hbar} } \sum_m \frac{V_\mathtt{nm}T_\mathtt{mi} \color{ magenta} { e^{i\omega_\mathtt{ni} t + \varepsilon t } } }{  \left(-\omega_\mathtt{mi}+i\varepsilon\right) \color{green}{ \left( -\omega_\mathtt{ni} + i\varepsilon \right) } }
\tag{IV}
$$
which is equivalent to (6.1.26) in Sakurai when all nonblack terms/factors are canceled. 
So I reiterate my question: where is my misinterpretation of the text.

Now, as I mentioned earlier, there may be folks who don't like such a specific question. So, as promised, here is an alternative question. If I were to have carried out the calculation from \eqref{6.1.24} I would arrive at:
$$
T_\mathtt{ni} = \frac{ -\omega_\mathtt{ni} + i\varepsilon }{V_\mathtt{nn}}\sum_{m \neq n} \frac{V_\mathtt{nm}T_\mathtt{mi}}{ -\omega_\mathtt{mi} + i\varepsilon }
\tag{V}\label{eqv}
$$
and the question becomes: what are the biggest clues that this result must not be physical?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so beautifully worked out that it is just enticing answers.

Let us get the basic stuff out of the way. You are definitely correct on most stuff.

> My specific question is why, after combining equations (6.1.23) and (6.1.24), the second of the 3 terms "looks just like (6.1.23), but with $T_{ni}$ replaced with $V_{ni}$"?
> I instead get that the first and second term combined look exactly like the right-hand-side of (6.1.10), except $t_0$ is replaced with $−\infty$.

That is very clearly a mental typo on the author's part. You are correct; In particular, your colourful Equation (IV) is exactly correct, and what Sakurai intended to say, is merely that the terms on the LHS and the first two terms on the RHS differ only in $T_{ni}$ v.s. $V_{ni}$, as you correctly deduced.

It really does not matter too much; you have correctly obtained Equation (6.1.26) as the thing that is really wanted to get anyway.

---

Now we can tackle the essence of your question, the elephant in the room.

> The structure of (V) is not at all like matrix elements for any other textbook QM quantity

This alone is not a problem. Just because it looks a little weird does not mean it is wrong. It is wrong for another reason, which we will soon come to, after the break. We should cover something more important first.

> The time-dependent perturbation theory developed in the previous chapter never required skipping index $m=n$

I am going to reinterpret what you are saying here. There is indeed nothing blocking $m=n$. There is, however, an important need that $i$ be handled separately, be it in $m$ or $n$, and it is a rather general rule. This is an important part to debunk. The book states clearly that, in the line right before Equation (5.278) specifically singled out that it only applies for $n\neq i$

Or, more concretely, before Equation (5.361) is also specifically said to be only for $n\neq i$ and Sakurai even specifically covered what happens to the initial state from Equation (5.366) onwards, and it is very much an intricate mess. But Sakurai did a good job there and explicitly showed the unitarity; the perturbation theory thus generated is satisfactory on this part. (I should forewarn you, however, that perturbation theory is plagued with renormalisation issues; the series thus generated are asymptotic, but they work phenomenally well despite mathematical insanities. The mathematical study of asymptotics is very interesting, though.)

We can also point out where things will go crazy from within the current set of stuff to look at. First of all, you should note that there are some commentary in the book around Equation (6.10). What is not stated, however, is that $0<\varepsilon\ll|\omega_{ni}|$ or some equivalent; it is only sensible because we are seeking for an imaginary perturbation for convergence, but $\omega_{ii}=0$ and so this can never be a suitable perturbation in any sense of the word. You can also check the commentary around Equation (6.13), where it is explicitly stated that $\left|i\right>\neq\left|n\right>$, referring, again, to Section 5.7, which is where Equation (5.278) as stated earlier, is.

In any case, if you had considered either of Equation (6.10), (6.13) or (6.23) and inserted the simultaneous condition that $\omega_{ii}=0=\varepsilon$, the denominator goes to zero and we have a singularity. Equation (6.10) does not give us a hope for solving this, because even if we just replaced the constant unity integration with the time $t-t_0$, the limit $t_0\to-\infty$ still gives us a singularity. It is also not clear how a Cauchy Principal Value scheme would help us avoid disaster.

---

Since Equation (IV) and (6.26) are correct, barring possible need to correct them when $n=i$, you are indeed correct to think of
$$\tag{VI}\left(1-\frac{V_{nn}}{E_i-E_n+i\hslash\varepsilon}\right)T_{ni}=V_{ni}+\sum_{m\neq n}\frac{V_{nm}T_{mi}}{E_i-E_m+i\hslash\varepsilon}$$
which follows from Equation (6.26) directly. This is what your Equation (V) should have been—you must have just made a computational mistake to have gotten Equation (V), or else you would have gotten this instead. This Equation (VI) is actually part of the steps getting to Equation (6.32), and arguments about such lead directly to renormalisation schemes in QFT. i.e. you are so close to getting deeper into understanding important stuff!

Now, I'm just going off vague memories here, but IIRC, the difference between Equation (6.32) and (VI) is due to the correct handling of the initial state. Please check this and do not take my word for it. The way to check, of course, is to work through the above with the stuff in Section 5.9 and make all the corrections needed to handle the initial state properly.

Comment: Thank you for response. Thinking in terms of (VI) will likely be useful tool in many instances. I could have been clearer about first part of my question. T_ni being replaced with V_ni is main discrepency between the text & what I get in (V), where terms  of T_ni on both sides cancel, so only way I get term of T_ni on its own is to "pull it out of" the sum across m, thus getting the sum across m != n. I may need to do some edits between (II) and (III) to highlight the terms of T_ni ( or <n|U|i> ) canceling. I did add an edit highlighting that what I got does not have T_ni replaced with V_ni

Comment: I think you are failing to absorb the very important distinction between Equation (6.1.9) and (6.1.10). In particular, you cannot take $t_0\to-\infty$ in Equation (6.1.9) because it is a first order approximation, a truncation of an infinite series expansion, so that $t-t_0$ cannot be too big, whereas Equation (6.1.10) is assumed to hold true for all $t_0$. So that means you cannot cancel everything left of the last term in Equation (IV) to obtain Equation (III), and because of that, you cannot arrive at Equation (V).

Comment: Yes, if $t_0=-\infty$ in 6.1.9, you need to identify it as 6.1.10, otherwise the integral is not solvable unless $t=\infty$. I do this identification after arriving at (II) and now have terms of $T_{ni}$ instead of $V_{ni}$; $T_{ni}$ is not replaced with $V_{ni}$ as suggested by the discussion between 6.1.24 & 6.1.25 and terms of $T_{ni}$ cancel.

Comment: My interpretation of discussion between 6.1.8 and 6.1.10 is that we are only solving the problem to first order in 5.7.6 and we define a T-matrix so that we can take $t_0→-\infty$ with $t\neq\infty$. If I cannot identify 6.1.9 as 6.1.10, then I certainly do not get terms of $T_{ni}$, but I also do not get 6.1.23 with $T_{ni}$ replaced with $V_{ni}$ when I arrive at (II), I just have an integral that can't be evaluated unless there's a way to do it via contour integration that I don't know.

Comment: That is where your interpretation is wrong. The discussion between Equations (6.1.8) and (6.1.10) are solely on analogy to get the correct choice of constants and parameters. There is no more use of Equation (6.1.9) from then on. So you cannot arrive at Equation (II) because that is just wrong. There is no invocation of contour integration.

Comment: Ok, so 6.1.9 is only first order in 5.7.6 whereas 6.1.10 can be [more] exact as long as we can find the right T-matrix, so we cannot equate the right-hand-sides of 6.1.9 and 6.1.10. This answers my less-specific question ( along with everything else in the original answer ). Thank you again

Comment: It is a good question